# XSLT identity transform produces wrong namespace

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I have a custom XML schema that is evolving: elements are added, others deleted, and the namespace changes to reflect the new version (e.g., from "http://foo/1.0" to "http://foo/1.1"). I want to write an XSLT that converts XML documents from the old schema to the new one. My first attempt works, but it's verbose and unscalable, and I need help refining it.

Here's a sample document for the 1.0 schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo:rootElement xmlns:foo="http://foo/1.0">
    <obsolete>something</obsolete>
    <stuff>
        <alpha>a</alpha>
        <beta>b</beta>
    </stuff>
</foo:rootElement>
```

In the 1.1 schema, the "obsolete" element goes away but everything else remains. So the XSLT needs to do two things:

1. Remove the  tag
2. Change the namespace from http://foo/1.0 to http://foo/1.1

Here's my solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:foo1="http://foo/1.0"
    xmlns:foo="http://foo/1.1" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="foo1">

    <xsl:output method="xml" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Remove the "obsolete" tag -->    
    <xsl:template match="foo1:rootElement/obsolete"/>

    <!-- Copy the "alpha" tag -->
    <xsl:template match="foo1:rootElement/stuff/alpha">
        <alpha>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </alpha>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Copy the "beta" tag -->
    <xsl:template match="foo1:rootElement/stuff/beta">
        <beta>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </beta>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Copy the "stuff" tag -->
    <xsl:template match="foo1:rootElement/stuff">
        <stuff>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </stuff>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Copy the "rootElement" tag -->
    <xsl:template match="foo1:rootElement">
        <foo:rootElement>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </foo:rootElement>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Although this produces the output I want, notice that I have a copying template for every element in the schema: alpha, beta, etc. For complex schemas with hundreds of kinds of elements, I'd have to add hundreds of templates!

I thought I could eliminate this problem by reducing all those copying templates into a single identity transform, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:foo1="http://foo/1.0"
    xmlns:foo="http://foo/1.1" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="foo1">

    <xsl:output method="xml" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="foo1:rootElement/obsolete"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foo1:rootElement/stuff">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foo1:rootElement">
        <foo:rootElement>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </foo:rootElement>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo:rootElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:foo="http://foo/1.1">  
    <stuff xmlns:foo="http://foo/1.0">
      <stuff>
        <alpha>a</alpha>
        <beta>b</beta>
      </stuff>
   </stuff>
</foo:rootElement>
```

The "stuff" element was copied, which is what I want, but it's wrapped in another "stuff" element, tagged with the old namespace. I don't understand why this is happening. I've tried many ways of fixing this but have been unsuccessful. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution. This is the only answer (of the currently two) that correctly processes attributes by copying them. Furthermore, even attributes belonging to the old namespace are correctly processed -- upgraded to the new namespace). The answer by @Gunther when applied on the XML document used in my answer, produces unwanted namespace node(s) of the old namespace. It also unnecessarily uses XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pOldNS" select="'http://foo/1.0'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pNewNS" select="'http://foo/1.1'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$pNewNS}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(.=$pOldNS)]"/>

   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="namespace-uri()=$pOldNS">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{$pNewNS}">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="obsolete"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<foo:rootElement xmlns:foo="http://foo/1.0">
    <obsolete>something</obsolete>
    <stuff>
        <alpha x="y" foo:t="z">a</alpha>
        <beta>b</beta>
    </stuff>
</foo:rootElement>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result** (`obsolute` elements deleted, namespace upgraded, attribute nodes correctly processed, including nodes that were in the old namespace):

```
<foo:rootElement xmlns:foo="http://foo/1.1">
   <stuff>
      <alpha x="y" foo:t="z">a</alpha>
      <beta>b</beta>
   </stuff>
</foo:rootElement>
```

**Main advantages of this solution**:

1. **Works correctly when there are attributes, belonging to the old-schema namespace**.
2. **General, allows the old and new namespace to be passed as external parameters** to the transformation.

Answer (score 2):

While you might want to copy the attributes, elements need to be regenerated in the new namespace. So I'd suggest to do it like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:foo1="http://foo/1.0">

    <xsl:template match="foo1:rootElement/obsolete"/>

    <xsl:template match="attribute()">
      <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element()">
      <xsl:variable name="name" select="local-name()"/>
      <xsl:element name="{$name}" namespace="http://foo/1.1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your transformation, when applied on the XML document used in my answer, produces the old namespace node. Try it.

Comment: @Dimitre, you are right, but this question was about moving elements into a new namespace. We have no indication of whether @vocaro is interested in attribute namespaces at all. I prefer to keep the response simple, and in this case I felt it does not harm to omit. Of course your answer complete, short and easy, and it does move attributes correctly: +1.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your explanation and it makes sense. You could add a notification about the assumptions of your solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gunther, but your solution doesn't get rid of the old namespace. As I stated, changing the namespace from 1.0 to 1.1 is a requirement for me. My original approach already achieves this; I just need something that is more scalable while producing equivalent output.